# How to change the levels of multiple factors at once

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling, r-factor

G'day,
I have a data frame with multiple factor variables.

I want to change the levels of all those factors variables to the same of levels.
They have all have 16 levels, which i would want to change to 7.

It already works for me if i to it like this:

```
data <-
data |>
  mutate(variable = fct_recode(
  variable,
    "new level" = "old level",
     "…"   = "…"
    "new level" = "old level"))
```

And this I could do for every single factor.

But since I have about 19 other factors I would prefer to do it with less boiler plate and not one for one.

So i am basically looking for a way to change the levels of all 19 factors at once

I tried some `across()`-stuff, but it did not quite worked out.

```
 level_mapping <- c(
  "new level" = "old level",
  "..." = "..."
  "new level" = "old level")

df_new <- df_old %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ fct_recode(., !!!level_mapping)))
```

I hope my question is understandable and any help would be appreciated

[Edit] I forgot to mention: While changing the factor levels, I would also like to drop one of them
An repex:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C")),
  var2 = factor(c("A", "B", "C")),
  var3 = factor(c("A", "B", "C"))
)

level_mapping <- c(
  "A" = "R",
  "B" = "E",
  "C" = "F")

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ recode(., !!!level_mapping))), "F" = NA)))
```

Comment: What exactly didn't work out with the `across` stuff? Did you get specific errors? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I added my code snippet

Comment: Thanks for adding the code snippet, but it's still not a reproducible example.  You could make a tiny reproducible example with (say) 3 factors with 3 levels each so we could play with it ...

Comment: Instead of `mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ fct_recode(., !!!level_mapping)))`  use `mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ recode(., !!!level_mapping)))`

Comment: I added one now. Hope it helps and thanks again

Comment: What happens when you try @TarJae's comment with your real data? (It works for me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code runs for me

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ recode(., !!!level_mapping, "F" = NA_character_)))
```

Recode was complaining about the `NA` value at first, but I changed it to use the strongly typed NA value. And mostly getting things to work just involved moving the parenthesis to the correct place.

Comment: Works for me too! Also noticed some problems in my dataframe I was able to fix. Thank you very much